# How do I control a Raspberry Pi from a non-local web server?

Tags: javascript, mysql, apache, raspberry-pi3

I currently have an apache server running on my raspberry pi that allows me to turn an LED on and off from any device on my home network. I use web sockets to communicate with the server running on my raspberry pi from the html page.

The next step i'd like take is to control the raspberry pi from a device not connected to my home network, and I'm at a complete loss on how to accomplish this. I was wondering if I could get a remote server communicating with the raspberry pi server if it was hosted on a site like Heroku, but I've never done anything like this before.

Here is my current code running/controlling the local apache server:

server.js:

```
var http = require('http').createServer(handler); //require http server, and create server with function handler()
var fs = require('fs'); //require filesystem module
var io = require('socket.io')(http) //require socket.io module and pass the http object (server)

http.listen(8080); //listen to port 8080

function handler (req, res) { //create server
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html', function(err, data) { //read file index.html in public folder
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}); //display 404 on error
      return res.end("404 Not Found");
    } 
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}); //write HTML
    res.write(data); //write data from index.html
    return res.end();
  });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {// WebSocket Connection
  var lightvalue = 0; //static variable for current status
  socket.on('light', function(data) { //get light switch status from client
    lightvalue = data;
    if (lightvalue) {
      console.log(lightvalue); //turn LED on or off, for now we will just show it in console.log
    }
  });
});
```

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Control LED light</h1>
<p><input type="checkbox" id="light"></p>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js"></script> <!-- include socket.io client side script -->
<script>
var socket = io(); //load socket.io-client and connect to the host that serves the page
window.addEventListener("load", function(){ //when page loads
  var lightbox = document.getElementById("light"); 
  lightbox.addEventListener("change", function() { //add event listener for when checkbox changes
    socket.emit("light", Number(this.checked)); //send button status to server (as 1 or 0)
  });
});
socket.on('light', function (data) { //get button status from client
  document.getElementById("light").checked = data; //change checkbox according to push button on Raspberry Pi
  socket.emit("light", data); //send push button status to back to server
});
</script>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Before this project, I had used a Python while loop to constantly read the values of a firebase real-time database. An LED would turn on and off depending on the value of a stored database variable. But I was informed that this is not a very efficient way of accomplishing what I wanted. However, this allowed me to control the raspberry pi from outside my home network. I'm just not sure how to accomplish this same thing with a web server.

Comment: The raspberry pi has an IP address given to it by your router.  It may be possible that that IP is not open to the web to access it directly.  If it is not, then the router would have to be configured to allow it to be publicly accessed.  Once it's publicly accessable, you can hit it from any machine connected to the internet.  However, keep in mind that unless you are paying your ISP for a static IP address, the chances that your IP may change over time do exist.

Comment: You'd have to set up port forwarding on your router to forward the connection from outside to the appropriate port(s) on the webserver. Be really careful about security though, you would need to have some authentication to secure the web app itself and the websocket endpoint. As a separate issue you might want to use a dynamic DNS service to give yourself a static hostname to access the server from the internet. Most domestic internet providers will not give you a static IP address and it's a pain if you're away from the house when it changes, as you'll lose access

Comment: In addition to those answers, you could also use websockets again to keep a constant connection open from your pi to your web server. Then, when you get a command on your web server, you can send it down to the pi via the open connection.

Comment: P.s. to be clear I don't think you need an extra web host (like heroku) here, you just need to (securely) expose the webserver you've already got to the internet

Comment: Port forwarding, which will allow access to your network from the internet. Then you can use Dynamic DNS mapped to a domain name and your WAN IP as an access point.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'll look into Port forwarding and dynamic DNS. I'm interested in what @Hassan said, would you mind elaborating a bit there? Would that essentially be some kind of server to server communication using websockets?

Comment: @Hassan the webserver is already located on the pi. I assume the intention eventually is to amend the server side code so it actually affects the physical LED rather than just logging a value. For that reason I don't think your suggested extra step is necessary

Comment: @Hassan As this point, the LED is already affected with the code I have posted above. But it's a local web-server. The issue is that I can't access it from anywhere outside my home network.

Comment: And for anyone who happens to stumble across this post in the future, I found this in the raspberry pi documentation: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/access-over-Internet/, and it shows alternatives to port forwarding. I'm currently looking into remote.it as it's free.

Comment: If you don't want to try to enable remote access, listening to a Firebase database is actually a pretty good idea, though I would recommend Firestore over Realtime Database and use the snapshot listener instead of constant polling inside a while loop. You could then set up Firebase hosting with a simple web app with the JavaScript Firebase libraries to let you toggle the LED.

Comment: Have a look at balena.io , they have a platform where you can define an application and they can route local port 80 to a public url. And you get a complete device managent service. (Just a user of the service, no shares :) )

Comment: @Herohtar Thanks! I'll take a look at that. I think going forward the group that I am working with are trying to implement a SQL database. But I might pursue that as an individual project and see how it works out.

Comment: You can use a remote GPIO library along with a reverse proxy server, like ngrok or frp. It is a cleaner approach than doing a port-forward.